# How do I get php executable path from Open Server in Windows?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have Open Server installed, it has php execution by default and I want to add it's ex path to vs code so that I could run php scripts from it in terminal. How do I get a relative path?

vs code settings.json:
`"php.validate.executablePath": "",`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use something like this:

```
"php.executablePath": "C:/OpenServer/modules/php/PHP-7/php.exe",
"php.validate.executablePath": "C:/OpenServer/modules/php/PHP-7/php.exe",
```

Remember to change the path to the place where you have OpenServer and also choose php version that you use.